# WPF Ribbon - Data templating in a RibbonTab

Tags: wpf, data-binding, ribbon

I've spent the better part of the last two days dinging around with this control and I'm stuck. Basically I don't how to data template it's RibbonTab. What I have would work for me if it would only not show it at the bottom of the RibbonTab! Grr!

What I have in my XAML is:

```
        <r:Ribbon Grid.Row="0" Title="MSRibbon" x:Name="ribbon">
            <r:Ribbon.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type r:Ribbon}">
                    <Setter Property="TabHeaderTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding AvailableRibbonTabs}"/>
                    <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding SelectedRibbonTab}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type r:RibbonTab}">
                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RibbonTabData}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </r:Ribbon.Style>
            <r:Ribbon.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmsrc:RecordingRibbonTabGroupData}">
                    <viewsrc:RecordingTabGroupControl/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </r:Ribbon.Resources>
        </r:Ribbon>
```

The XAML of the control i would like to show in the ribbon tab group is (this, when displayed gets glued to the bottom of the ribbon tab):

```
<r:RibbonControl x:Class="Scanner.Views.RecordingRibbonTabGroupData">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <r:RibbonButton Label="foo" />
    <r:RibbonButton Label="bar" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Barcodes}" />
    </StackPanel>
</r:RibbonControl>
```

Here I tried using different combinations of controls but to no effect. As the control base type I used the RibbonTab, the RibbonGroup, UserControl etc and I think I used every possible control as the main container, like StackPanel, Grid, ItemsControl, etc.. And also experimented with setting the Heights of every control and H/V alignment, etc. Nothing helped.

My view models are such (INPC is injected with INPCWeaver and it works):

```
public abstract class AbstractViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public abstract class AbstractRibbonTab : AbstractViewModel
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<AbstractRibbonTabGroupData> RibbonTabData { get; set; }
}



public class RecordingRibbonTab : AbstractRibbonTab
{
    public RecordingRibbonTab()
    {
        this.Header = "Recording";
        this.RibbonTabData = new ObservableCollection<AbstractRibbonTabGroupData>() { new RecordingRibbonTabGroupData() };
    }
}

public class SessionRibbonTab : AbstractRibbonTab
{
    public SessionRibbonTab()
    {
        this.Header = "Session";
        this.RibbonTabData = new ObservableCollection<AbstractRibbonTabGroupData>() { new AbstractRibbonTabGroupData() };
    }
}

public class SettingsRibbonTab : AbstractRibbonTab
{
    public SettingsRibbonTab()
    {
        this.Header = "Settings";
        this.RibbonTabData = new ObservableCollection<AbstractRibbonTabGroupData>() { new AbstractRibbonTabGroupData() };
    }
}
```

The XAML has it's data context set to an instance of:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : AbstractViewModel, IMainWindowViewModel
{
    ...
    public ObservableCollection<AbstractRibbonTab> AvailableRibbonTabs { get; private set; }
    public AbstractRibbonTab SelectedRibbonTab { get; set; }
    ...
    public MainWindowViewModel(PinChangeCommand pcc)
    {
        this.AvailableRibbonTabs = new ObservableCollection<AbstractRibbonTab>();
        this.AvailableRibbonTabs.Add(new RecordingRibbonTab());
        this.AvailableRibbonTabs.Add(new SessionRibbonTab());
        this.AvailableRibbonTabs.Add(new SettingsRibbonTab());
    }
 }
```

The bindings work.

As a side note, below the ribbon there is a content control declared like so

```
        <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding SelectedRibbonTab}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vmsr:RecordingRibbonTab}">
                    <views:RecordingView />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
```

that works perfectly fine as one would expect.

The 'recording' view that I did implement has the following XAML (it just shows the header, as one can see in the screenshot below):

```
<UserControl x:Class="Scanner.Views.RecordingView">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Wrapping up, a code listing that should explain some strange numbers:

```
public class RecordingRibbonTabGroupData : AbstractRibbonTabGroupData
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Barcodes { get; private set; }

    public RecordingRibbonTabGroupData()
    {
        this.Barcodes = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        this.Barcodes.Add("76765535642");
        this.Barcodes.Add("43435356");
    }
}
```

Without DataTemplate: [image: Without DataTemplate]

WITH DataTemplate: [image: WITH DataTemplate]

Comment: can you post a link to a screenshot?

Comment: great idea, thank you.
[without template](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/2835/withoutdatatemplate.jpg)
[with template](http://img859.imageshack.us/img859/7723/withdatatemplate.jpg)

Comment: i rearranged the question and added some details in hope it'd be clearer.

Comment: maybe it's defaulted to show up at the bottom.  have you tried setting any `VerticalAlignment="Top"` or `VerticalContentAlignment="Top"` on the controls?

Comment: it's not about that but about the available space, because if i set the height of the ie listbox then i can only see a fraction of it.

Comment: have you tried commenting all of your custom styles, templates, etc. for the MS controls?  does anything change when you do comment them?  or, are you creating your own Ribbon controls?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is two ItemContainerStyle

```
 <Ribbon:Ribbon ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RibbonTabStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding DummyRibbonTabContent}">
```

first:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Ribbon:RibbonTab}" x:Key="RibbonTabStyle">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DummyRibbonGroups}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource RibbonGroupStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding DummyRibbonHeader"} />
</Style>
```

second:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Ribbon:RibbonGroup}" x:Key="RibbonGroupStyle">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding RibbonGroupHeader}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding DummyRibbonButtons}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource RibbonButtonTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Obviously you have to create a ribbon button datatemplate. You could also use item templateselector for the ribbongroupstyle and then you can add not just ribbonbuttons but whatever you wish. Its not the exact solution you need, but I hope you get the idea.